# Samba filesharing to Win7

Tags: networking, virtualization, samba

I'm a novice network admin tasked with setting up a pretty simple file share structure for a small non-profit I volunteer for. I wanted to test this in-house because I've only ever worked with Windows systems before, and this would be an Ubuntu server running Samba (for ease of filesharing with the Macs at the office, as well as budget concerns with Windows Server licenses).

I have a Win7 VirtualBox Host at 192.168.1.3, running Ubuntu Server 10.4 in Bridge mode at 192.168.1.6. When I try to connect to any Samba shares from the Host, I get a standard Windows "cannot access" error message. The host machine can ping the guest machine but not vice-versa. `sudo ufw disable` did not change this. `sudo iptables --list` is blank (that is to say: default ACCEPT on all three chains with no rules)

What's my next troubleshooting step?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by digging deeper into my network config and making sure all the relevant ports were allowed through `ufw`. The [Ubuntu community help page for `ufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) was a great resource for this. For some reason just doing `sudo ufw disable` wasn't enough, I had to specifically allow those ports then it worked like a charm.

I ran the following commands as root:

```
ufw allow 137/tcp
ufw allow 137/udp
ufw allow 138/tcp
ufw allow 138/udp
ufw allow 139/tcp
ufw allow 139/udp
ufw allow 445/tcp
```

Answer (score 0):

As Windows 7 is the host, when you create a shared directory, the default permission set is restrictive.

On the odd chance, did you remember to add 'Everyone' to both Share and NTFS permissions for troubleshooting?

Also remember, always try the basic first. I can't see how checking iptables would have helped you, which is probably why you've gotten stuck :)

Comment: Win7 is the host machine for the virtual machine. Ubuntu Server is running the file server.

Comment: Ahh, otherway around - My apologies :)

Comment: No problem. My head starts spinning any time we start virtualizing, too! :)

Comment: lol likewise. My experience ends with creating a Virtualized windows server installation running remoteApp for a company I deployed a serevr to :)